# Назначение родителя

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать, чтобы код `<input type="text">` отображался вот так:
`<span><input type="text"><icon src="..."></icon></span>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если input уже на странице:

```
$('input[type=text]').wrap('<span />').after('<icon src="..."></icon>');
```

Селектор поля, если нужно, укажите точнее. Только я что-то не припомню тега <icon>, поэтому [в этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/95jfuwzo/) использовал обычный <img>

Comment: Этот тег я сам сделал, он просто иконку добавляет.

Comment: Используйте существующие теги, например <i>.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй. Если я правильно понял задачу, то так:

```
$('span').prepend($('input'));
```